# reveal.js to single page html

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, singlepage

I was wondering if there was a simple way to go from a reveal.js slideshow to a single page html. I don't want to create two file with the same data. I feel that I should be able to easily go from the slideshow to a single page.

Would removing the reveal.js scripts work? If so, how can I do that dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone with a javascript function using jQuery that dynamically strips the page of specific classes and elements.